# JQuery append insert two duplicate rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I am creating master detail in asp.net core application using jquery and javascript but on click of add button to append new row , I find that the row is repeated twice, and I do not know the reason for that.
When I clicked add button, the row is repeated twice as shown in the image[image]

Below is my javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        AddToList();

    });
});
function AddToList() {
    var ItemTable = $("#detailsTable");
    var bookID = $("#booklist").val();
    var bookName = $("#booklist option:selected").text();
    var Price = $("#Price").val();
    var Quantity = $("#Quantity").val();
    var Amount = $("#Amount").val();
    var itemList = "<tr><td hidden>" +
        bookID +
        "</td><td>" +
        bookName +
        "</td><td>" +
        parseFloat(Price).toFixed(2) +
        "</td><td>" +
        parseFloat(Quantity).toFixed(2) +
        "</td><td>" +
        parseFloat(Amount).toFixed(2) 
        + "</td><td> <input type='button' id='Remove' value='Remove' name='remove' style='width:80px' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='RemoveItem(this)' /> </td></tr></tr>";

    ItemTable.append(itemList);
    //ResetTable();
}
```

this razor page of master–detail

```html
  <table class="table table-hover col-md-12" id="detailsTable">
                                       <thead>

                                           <tr>
                                               <th>Book</th>
                                               <th>Price</th>
                                               <th>Quantity</th>
                                               <th>Amount</th>
                                               <th></th>

                                           </tr>
                                       </thead>

                                       <tbody>
                                           <tr class="mycontainer">

                                               <td>
                                                   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Book.Bookid,
                        new SelectList(Model.Books.Select(x => new { Value = x.Bookid, Text = x.Title }), "Value", "Text"), "Select a Book",
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "bookli form-control border-input", @id = "booklist" })
                                                   <span class="error">Valid Book Title required</span>

                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                   <input asp-for="Book.price" type="text" id="Price" class="Price form-control" readonly />
                                                   @*<span class="error">Valid Price required</span>*@

                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                   <input asp-for="Book.Quantity" type="text" id="Quantity" class="Quantity form-control" />
                                                   @*<span class="error">Valid quantity required</span>*@
                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                   <input asp-for="Book.Amount" type="text" id="Amount" class="Amount form-control" readonly />
                                                   @*<span class="error">Valid Amount required</span>*@
                                               </td>
                                               <td>
                                                   <input type="button" id="add" value="add" style="width:80px" class="btn btn-success" />
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                   </table>
```

can any one help me plzzzzz :( ?

Comment: The codes you shared doesn't seem to produce this. Do you have any other call to the AddToList function?

Comment: You have two closing `<tr>` tags at end of string `</tr></tr>`

Comment: I ran your code and there was no duplication. Probably the problem is not with the code you provided

Comment: Double check you aren't loading the same code twice also. Add a console log inside the function...if you see it twice the code is being run twice

Comment: @AndreiShadowS No, i remove all anthor code in javascript file but the same problem

Comment: @charlietfl yes,i add console log inside the function and see it twice

Comment: So somewhere in your code, the AddToList is called twice. You can use console.trace() to see from where was the call made. Just add that line in your function. I usually place it as the first line. If you view the console you'll see the name of your function, and below that line, you'll see where it's being called from.

Answer (score 0):

```
you should use append function to your table body. here you need to assign your id to <tbody>.

Html code :-

            <table class="table" id='tbl'>
                <tr>
                   <th>...</th>
                </tr>
              <tbody id='tbody'>

              </tbody>
            </table>


Javascript code :-

$('#tbody').append("<tr><td>...</td></tr>");
```